# Xcode sketch on map

Tags: xcode, google-maps, kml

I want to make an application in Xcode that sketch or show my track path that I walked on the map view. I have searched a lot but couldn't find any thing to start about this topic. I have read a lot about KML but couldn't find my answer.  So please could you tell me how to draw the path I walk? Is there a tutorial or sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really cool app that is open source, and does basically what you are talking about it and more, and it's open source.  The app is [AntiMap Log](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/antimap-log/id486524181?mt=8) and it's source can be found [here](https://github.com/trentbrooks/AntiMap/tree/master/AntiMapLog).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesn't show me my line that I walked on the map this app only log my data. I can give you an example like RunKeeper app it sketch your walk on the map etc.

Thanks again.